# Известны первые буквы файла, но остальные нет, нужно найти файл

Tags: c#, файлы, регулярные-выражения, файловая-система

Имеется такой код:

```
string folderWithFiles = "C:\\";
                                Directory.GetFiles(folderWithFiles, "ssfn.*").ToList().ForEach(name => mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(name, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet)));
                                sc.Send(mm);
```

Известны первые буквы файла - "ssfn", но остальные и их количество неизвестны. Как найти этот файл хотя бы с помощью регулярок? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точку уберите `GetFiles(folderWithFiles, "ssfn*")`

Comment: Напишите это в ответе, и вы мой бог))) Будет лучший ответ, спс помогло!! мучался 4 часа, большое спасибо!